# CRT (c++) и unit test

Tags: c++, visual-studio, утечка-памяти

Я недавно узнал, что можно проверять программу на предмет утечки памяти через метод `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();`. Т.е. можно сделать следующее:

```
int main(){
int* ptr = new int;
ptr = 5;

_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
return 0;
}
```

В результате в `output` появиться соответствующее сообщение об ошибке.

Вопрос в том как внедрить этот метод в юнит тест, так как если написать тот же код в тестирующем методе в консоли вывода ничего не появится.

Comment: А вам имено надо, чтобы эта информация появилась в консоле или вы как-то программно хотите проверять наличее утечек? Также похоже что эта функция работат только в дебаге

Comment: @Unick Если можно сделать так, чтобы unit тест не проходил при утечке памяти, то это было бы идеально.